# Run an inner observable without the result affecting the outer observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Is there a way to run an inner observable like `switchMap`, `concatMap`, etc. but without without changing the outer observable value? What I have here is that the inner observable in the switchMap is converting the `string` to a `boolean` and passing that result along the pipe. How can I get it to just pass what was passed in to get passed out?

```js
  fsExists = false;
  projectExists = false;

  private doChecks = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  doChecks$ = this.doChecks.pipe(
    debounceTime(100),
    tap(i => (this.projectExists = this.projects.exists(i))),
    // Converts the outer `i` to a boolean here:
    switchMap(i => this.fs.exists(path.join(i, environment.manifest)).pipe(tap(i => (this.fsExists = i)))),
    tap(i => /* `i` should be a string here. But it is a boolean. */)
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `map` to return the original parameter, you might want to name the variables differently to make it less confusing. I renamed the boolean instance of `i` to `exists` to be clear.

```js
  doChecks$ = this.doChecks.pipe(
    debounceTime(100),
    tap((i) => (this.projectExists = this.projects.exists(i))),
    switchMap((i) =>
      this.fs.exists(path.join(i, environment.manifest)).pipe(
        tap((exists) => (this.fsExists = exists)),
        map(() => i) // return original parameter of switchMap
      )
    ),
    tap((i) => console.log(i)) // i is string here
  );
```